# SaaS - best technology to choose

Tags: asp.net-mvc, saas

I have to develop an application similar to Google Docs with some special requirements: to be a SaaS and to work both online and offline?

Which technologies would be the most suitable? Is ASP.NET MVC compatible with this kind of demands? If so, how is it possible to make it work offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is ASP.NET MVC compatible with this kind of demands?

You can use any server side technology you like.

> If so, how is it possible to make it work offline?

With a combination of [Cache Manifest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_manifest_in_HTML5) (note: [limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=offline-apps)) to make the files for the application available offline and a [Web Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage) technology (Note: [reasonable browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20storage)) to store the data (which you'll have to sync with the server when it becomes available if it want it shared between systems/browsers).

Comment: In this case the application will have to run the first time online, right? In order to have the files available offline

Comment: Yes, of course. The website is, effectively, the installer for the offline application.